# Reinstall Cups after unloading/removing its LaunchDaemon

Tags: printing, daemons, cups

On one of our laptops, we had popups about printer settings update 200 times per day.
It was getting really annoying and so without thinking about it enough, I've unload and remove cups service.

```
 sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.cups.cupsd.plist
 sudo launchctl remove /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.cups.cupsd.plist
```

Popups are gone. But unfortunately, now we need Cups back and I can't figure out how to install it again.
Could you explain the installation process for Cups? and launchdaemons maybe?

Running any `lpadmin` command return `lpadmin: Unable to connect to server: Bad file descriptor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the commands I ran to solve this issue:

```
sudo launchctl stop org.cups.cupsd
sudo mv /etc/cups/cupsd.conf /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.backup
sudo cp /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.default /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
sudo mv /etc/cups/printers.conf /etc/cups/printers.conf.backup
sudo launchctl start org.cups.cupsd
```

Then I've reset the Printing System as suggested here:
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203343

Then simply add your printers again.

Comment: Why is the creation of backup files required to relaunch CUPS?

Comment: I wanted to keep my printer's settings in case it didn't work.

Comment: You've not reinstalled it: just restarted it, haven't you?

Comment: More kind of reset it and restarted it after, you're right.